# mnisten make fails with error makefile:2: recipe for target 'mnisten' failed make: *** [mnisten] Error 1

Tags: make

I am trying to compile mnisten using `g++ -Wall -O2 -libboost_filesystem -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp`, it fails with error

```
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:277:19458: warning: null character(s) ignored
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:277:7: error: stray ‘\177’ in program
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:277:19465: warning: null character(s) ignored
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:277:7: error: stray ‘\1’ in program
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:277:19480: warning: null character(s) ignored
In file included from src/main.cpp:16:0:
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:1:2: error: ‘ELF’ does not name a type
 ELF          >    �o      @       ��         @ 8  @                
  ^
/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so:2:24: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
                     P}     P}!     P}!                             �
                        ^
makefile:2: recipe for target 'mnisten' failed
make: *** [mnisten] Error 1
```

Comment: How are you getting output from `make` when you're running `g++`?

Comment: @ChaiT. Rex, I was using mnisten from https://github.com/nyanp/mnisten/, while compiling using makefile i modified the file lboost_filesystem-mt to libboost_filesystem as it was changed in the later version of boost, it gives the error

Answer (score 1):

### The problem

It says `In file included from src/main.cpp:16:0`, then has errors trying to use a `.so` library file as if it's a C++ source file. `.so` files are definitely not C++ source files, so of course you'll have errors there.

Look at line 16 of `src/main.cpp` and see what's going wrong there. You're probably doing something like `#include "/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so"`.

`#include` is to be used only to include C++ source files (typically `.h` files). It's never to be used for `.so` files.

### The solution

`g++`'s `-L` option can be used to tell it where binary libraries are located and its `-l` option can be used to tell it to use a specific library.

Note that `-lname` will try to use `libname.so`, so you don't want the `lib` portion of the name included, or you'll get the problem that `-libname` tries to use `libibname.so`.

1. Remove any `#include` lines that include `.so` files.
2. Change `g++ -Wall -O2 -libboost_filesystem -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp` to something like:

   ```
   g++ -Wall -O2 -L/home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib -lboost_filesystem -std=c++0x -o mnisten src/main.cpp
   ```

   You can alternatively just put the full path to the `.so` file like so:

   ```
   g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++0x -o mnisten /home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so src/main.cpp
   ```

Comment: yes I added #include </home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so> to the main.cpp since it was giving error /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -libboost_filesystem collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: OK, I've added a section on a possible solution.

Comment: T.Rex , I have modified the  make file with both option given in step 2, getting the following error     make
g++ -Wall -O2 -std=c++0x -o mnisten /home/dell/boost_1_55_0/stage/lib/libboost_filesystem.so src/main.cpp


main.cpp:(.text.startup+0x921): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:2: recipe for target 'mnisten' failed
make: *** [mnisten] Error 1

Comment: T.Rex     - the following are the additional log                                                      main.cpp:(.text+0x889): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::codecvt()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xaf4): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb78): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'
main.cpp:(.text+0xb98): undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
main.cpp:(.text+0xc20): undefined reference to `cv::fastFree(void*)'